# Keeping Firefox's places.sqlite file from consuming too much space in Time Machine bakckups

Tags: time-machine, backup, firefox, browser-history

My Time Machine backups often consist of Firefox's places.sqlite file (which, as I understand it, contains both history and bookmarks) and little else. When I clear my browsing history the file shrinks by about 80%. I think I have the following options:

1. Live with it
2. Exclude places.sqlite from being backed up and risk losing my bookmarks
3. Tell Firefox not to track history

Is there another option under which I track history without burning space to back it up?

BTW, [running sqlite vacuum](http://hints.macworld.com/comment.php?mode=view&cid=106994) helps some, shrinking places.sqlite by about a factor of two. The command is `sqlite3 places.sqlite "vacuum;"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Set Firefox to auto-export your bookmarks on close to bookmarks.html in your profile and then exclude places.sqlite from being backed up.

See this support article: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.bookmarks.autoExportHTML